# restart a php script using shell script

Tags: shell, process, kill, ps

i am using shell script to monitor the working of a php script. My aim is that this php script should not sleep / terminated and must always be running.The code i used is -

```
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -q $file || ( nohup php -f $file -print > /var/log/file.log & )
```

now this idea would not work for cases if the php script got terminated(process status code T). Any idea to handle that case. can such processes be killed permanently and then restarted.

Comment: What is your PHP script doing that it must always be running? Wouldn't it be simpler to use a different language?

Comment: @amphetamachine, I'm all in favor of people moving away from PHP, but the problem would be the same in almost any target language. :)

Comment: Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the script is exiting after it's been terminater, or if it crashes out, and needs to be restarted, a simple shell script can take care of that.

```
#!/bin/bash
# runScript.sh - keep a php script running
php -q -f ./cli-script.php -- $@
exec $0 $@;
```

The `exec $0` re-runs the shell script, with the parameters it was given.

To run in the background you can `nohup runScript.sh` or run it via init.d scripts, upstart, runit or supervisord, among others.

Answer (score 2):

How about just restarting the php interpreter when it dies?

```
while true ; do php -f $file -print >> /var/log/file.log ; done
```

Of course, someone could send the script a `SIGSTOP`, `SIGTSTP`, `SIGTTIN`, `SIGTTOU` to cause it to hang, but perhaps that person has a really good reason. You can block them all except `SIGSTOP`, so maybe that's alright.

Or if the script does something like call `read(2)` on a device or socket that will never return, this won't really ensure the 'liveness' of your script. (But then you'd use non-blocking IO to prevent *this* situation, so that's covered.)

Oh yes, you could also stuff it into your /etc/inittab. But I'm not giving you more than a hint about this one, because I think it is probably a bad idea.

And there are many similar tools that already exist: [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) and [Linux Heartbeat](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Main_Page) are the first two to come to mind.

Comment: If you're going to be sending IPC signals, don't forget about [PHP's ability to trap them](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php).

Comment: that i am already doing by running this script through a cron job. My doubt is though how to handle cases where the process gets a T status code.??/

Comment: @ayush, as amphetamachine mentions, you can block or ignore `SIGTSTP`, `SIGTTIN`, and `SIGTTOU`. You cannot block or ignore `SIGSTOP`, but if someone is sending the process `SIGSTOP` there must be a good reason. You can also drastically reduce the chances of someone tracing your script and thus causing it to sleep: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Roadmap/KernelHardening#ptrace